# How to run application with OWIN on IIS immediately?

Tags: asp.net, iis, owin

I have application which is hosted on IIS and uses OWIN. As usually I have Startup class. When I publish application to IIS and restart it then application doesn't start until I send request from browser. But I want to make application start immediately without any request after it was deployed, restarted or application pool was recycled.

I tried to use ServiceAutoStartProvider like it is described [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series). But I could not call Startup from Preload method.

Is there any other way to run application immediately?